# Flutter: Chrome settings are reset every time I run my Flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Whenever I run my Flutter app on Chrome - settings and local storage seem to be reset.

For example, indexeddb is deleted, and custom flags I set in chrome://flags are reset.

I guess that it's because Flutter starts Chrome in a "guest" profile.

How can I get Flutter to launch Chrome under a "regular" profile?

I would love to know how to set this up in Android Studio, but if not possible, then command-line is also ok.

Comment: Just found this [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43809)
In short: `flutter run -d web-server` then copy the link to a regular chrome started by you. However, you won't be able to debug...

Comment: Thanks @balee. I gave up on Flutter web already. I feel like the Flutter team has bitten more than they can chew on this one. It's just not good enough (or at least it wasn't back in 2021 :) )